# I want to have the top tab stay on when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I am using this menu found here:
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/horizontal-subnav/

Problem I am having is that I want to have the Top Nav stay when clicked and showing the subs also. I hope anyone can help me out!

The Top Nav should still be active when the new page is loaded. I know how to do this server-side but not client-side with JS/jQuery

Answer (score 0):

With a quick view at the page source I find this jQuery code that handles the hover event:

```
$("ul#topnav li").hover(function() { //Hover over event on list item
    $(this).css({ 'background' : '#1376c9 url(topnav_active.gif) repeat-x'}); //Add background color + image on hovered list item
    $(this).find("span").show(); //Show the subnav
} , function() { //on hover out...
    $(this).css({ 'background' : 'none'}); //Ditch the background
    $(this).find("span").hide(); //Hide the subnav
});
```

If you want the subnav bar to stay visible after a click or something just create an if() statement within the 'hover out' function that checks if something has been clicked, i.e.

```
} , function() { //on hover out...
    $(this).css({ 'background' : 'none'}); //Ditch the background
    if(subnavclick==0){
        $(this).find("span").hide(); //Hide the subnav
    }
});
```

And within your subnav .click() function add the setting of the `subnavclick` variable like so:

```
 $("span").click(function(){
   subnavclick==1;
   //do other stuff
 });
```

This should work for you....

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
    $("ul#topnav li").hover(function() { //Hover over event on list item
      $(this).css({ 'background' : '#1376c9 url(topnav_active.gif) repeat-x'}); //Add background color + image on hovered list item
      $(this).find("span").show(); //Show the subnav
} , function() { //on hover out...
      $(this).css({ 'background' : 'none'}); //Ditch the background
      $(this).find("span").hide(); //Hide the subnav
    });
```

to

```
    $("ul#topnav li").click(function() { //Hover over event on list item
      $(this).css({ 'background' : '#1376c9 url(topnav_active.gif) repeat-x'}); //Add background color + image on hovered list item
      $(this).find("span").show(); //Show the subnav
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the effect on a mouseover event as stated in the script now, you should make it work on [the click event](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the js code is redundant as the functionality is provided by css anyway. Just add a "clicked" class that mimics the hover pseudo-class of the li's and add and remove this on click.

http://jsfiddle.net/VirusZ/THYsK/

Also you must update the z-indices so that the submenus appear on hover even with a clicked element visible.

Comment: It worked as long as i dont load a new page, all the sub-nav links in the menu is calling a new page. So how can I keep the active statement when loading a new page ? Maybe I was not so clear of what I wanted.

Comment: @n3tx In this case you have to do what @Dutchie432 suggested: ajax retrieval. This is rather complex and you would have to learn a bit of javascript if you don't know already. I personally use jQuery to make life easier: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/. Also I recommend reading this: https://github.com/balupton/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling. It is a great library used to permit state handling without page refresh.

Comment: @n3tx also you can check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VirusZ/THYsK/4/ for a quick example of listening for clicks on the anchors and asynchronously retrieving/replacing content.

Answer (score 0):

To generalize, you'll need to do this in your CSS file and in the JS. You'll want to find `ul#topnav li:hover{...}` and clone it to something like `ul#topnav li.active{...}`. This is the class we will apply to the currently selected menu item.

```
ul#topnav li.current{
    background: #f00 url(topnav_current.gif) repeat-x;
}
```

From there, it will depend on exactly how your site will work. Will each Tab bring you to a new page, or will clicking a tab trigger an ajax retrieval?

If you're using AJAX, you can capture the LI's click events to set a class. ([LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/XGZyy/)). If you're going with a new page on every click, you will need to have JS parse the url and set the correct item's class using `$(item).addClass('current');`